# Pass params to JS inside <object type="text/html"> in IE

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to embed one page into another using technique described at http://aplus.rs/web-dev/insert-html-page-into-another-html-page (as an alternative to iframe):

```
< !--[if IE] >  
< object classid="clsid:25336920-03F9-11CF-8FD0-00AA00686F13" data="some.html" >< /object >  
< ![endif]-- > 
< !--[if !IE]> <--> 
< object type="text/html" data="some.html" >< /object >  
< !-- > < ![endif]-- >
```

I need to pass some parameters into embedded page so JS inside embedded page can obtain them and deal with. Currently I'm using query string for:

```
< object type="text/html" data="some.html?someParam=someValue" >< /object >
```

I can access document.location.href using JS from embedded page, parse it and obtain parameters passed-in. It works fine in all browsers. Except IE...

In IE "document" property refers document of the parent page, not the embedded page... As a result I can't access its query string.

So the question: how to get it work in all browsers? May be there is another way to pass params into the embedded page (using OBJECT tag's properties)...

Thanks, 
Igor

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled across this while looking for something else. As there were no answers, I thought this might be useful: http://feather.elektrum.org/book/src.html

About half way down it talks about making scripts self-aware, to get the url params, which seems like what you're trying? You might be able to adapt the code under "**The -obstacle- challenge**"